# Makefile order, doesn't compile everything

Tags: c, makefile

I have a makefile with this simple rules,

```
ref_approx_bs2_rsq_5_10_1ulp_arch1 : ref_approx_bs2_rsq_5_10_1ulp_arch1.o
    gcc -I../CModels -L../CModels -std=c99 -o ref_approx_bs2_rsq_5_10_1ulp_arch1 ref_approx_bs2_rsq_5_10_1ulp_arch1.o -lm -limg_float 

ref_approx_bs2_rsq_5_10_1ulp_arch1.o : ref_approx_rsq.c ../CModels/cogen_fp_bs2_rsq_5_10_1ulp_arch1.cpp ../CModels/cogen_fp_bs2_rsq_5_10_1ulp_arch1.h ../CModels/img_float.h ../CModels/img_float.c 
    gcc  -DCMODELLOC=\"../CModels/cogen_fp_bs2_rsq_5_10_1ulp_arch1.cpp\" -DCMODEL_NAME=cogen_fp_bs2_rsq_5_10_1ulp_arch1 -std=c99 -o ref_approx_bs2_rsq_5_10_1ulp_arch1.o -c ref_approx_rsq.c
libimg_float.a : ../CModels/img_float.o 
    ar -rcs ../CModels/libimg_float.a ../CModels/img_float.o 
img_float.o : ../CModels/img_float.h ../CModels/img_float.c 
    gcc -I ../CModels/ -o ../CModels/img_float.o -c ../CModels/img_float.c
```

But basically if I modify img_float.c and try to use the make file again it doesn't compile and create libimg_float.a.

The makefile itself looks correct to me since I've written all the prerequisites.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is `../CModels/img_float.o` the same as `img_float.o`?

Comment: should the target of the rule contains the relative path too? i thought it was just a name. is the error in the prerequisites of some rule? or in the target name of some rule? (i haven't thought in that way actually...)

Comment: the left side says 'what file to build' the right side says 'what files it depends on' and the next lines says 'how to transform the files on the right side into the file on the lft side'

Comment: So basically the last line (for instance) says "build in the current directory img_float.o", while the last but one it search in "../CModels/img_float.o" ? But i don't get anyway... since the last line builds img_float.o in the ../CModels (this indeed is what happens...) so the other lines should look at the correct file isn't?

Comment: An old issue but worth checking...  Is your system time accurate?  Timestamps coupled with dependencies is really how make decides what needs to be recompiled.

Comment: what do you mean with "time accurate" and how do i check? If you mean "the file reports modify data" that's true.

Comment: A stupid question... should the rules need to be separated by newline character?

Comment: @Lukkio : no empty line required between rules

Answer (score 1):

It won't recompile `libimg_float.a` because nothing depends on it.

Make doesn't go through your makefile and always try to rebuild every target.  Make works by finding the *first* (explicit) target listed and trying to build that.  Before building the first target, it will try to build all the prerequisites of that target, and before that it will try to build all the prerequisites of *those* targets, etc. until no more prerequisites are found.

If there is a target which is not a prerequisite of the first target (or its prerequisites, etc.) then it will not be built, by default.  You can request that it be built by listing it on the command line: `make libimg_float.a` will tell make to build that target, *instead of* the first explicit target.  Of course you can list lots of targets on the command line.

But generally people create one target first, commonly called `all`, which lists all the targets that should be built by default as a prerequisite.

Here, though, your makefile is not right because your `ref_approx_bs2_rsq_5_10_1ulp_arch1` target *does* use `libimg_float.a`, but it's not listed as a prerequisite.  That means it won't be updated when `libimg_float.a` is out of date.  You should change your makefile to show that prerequisite relationship:

```
ref_approx_bs2_rsq_5_10_1ulp_arch1 : ref_approx_bs2_rsq_5_10_1ulp_arch1.o libimg_float.a
```